# Linq2Sql slowing down after a short while

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

In a bigger project we decided to use Linq2Sql in the web-services (WCF). We 'quickly' found out that after some data has been added (through a small console app importing customer data) the web-service slowed down - apperantly for the lifetime duration of that app.

Every time we restarted the app it seemingly imported data fast in the beginning, and then slowing down after maybe 10-15 minutes of import.

I decided to try to just create a sample app mimicking small parts of our main app.

- I have to add, we decided to leave out Linq2Sql in the web services replacing them with reqular sqlcommand/SqlConnection etc.

Do anyone have a clue as to what this slowing down of an app might be caused by?

Here's the code for the "minimized" app mimicking some database queries:

App including SQL statements to create the tables:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

namespace Linq2SqlTest
{
    class Program
    {
        /*
         * USE [Linq2SqlTest]
            GO
            SET ANSI_NULLS ON
            GO
            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
            GO
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Adresse](
                [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                [person_id] [int] NOT NULL,
                [Gate] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
                [Poststed] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
                [By] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
             CONSTRAINT [PK_Adresse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
                [id] ASC
            )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
            ) ON [PRIMARY]

            GO
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Adresse]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Adresse_Person1] FOREIGN KEY([person_id])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([id])
            GO
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Adresse] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Adresse_Person1]
         * 
         * 
         * USE [Linq2SqlTest]
            GO
            SET ANSI_NULLS ON
            GO
            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
            GO
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
                [ItemID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                [ItemNumber] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
                [PersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
                [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
             CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
                [ItemID] ASC
            )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
            ) ON [PRIMARY]

            GO
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Person] FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([id])
            GO
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Person]

         *
         * USE [Linq2SqlTest]
                GO
                SET ANSI_NULLS ON
                GO
                SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
                GO
                CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
                    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
                    [AddedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
                    [ssn] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
                 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
                (
                    [id] ASC
                )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
                ) ON [PRIMARY]

         */

        public static Random randomizer = new Random();

        public static String GenerateName()
        {
            int nLetterCount = (randomizer.Next() % 5) + 3;

            String s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < nLetterCount;i++)
            {
                int r = (randomizer.Next() % 26)+97;
                s += Convert.ToChar(r);
            }
            return s;
        }
        public static String GenerateFullname()
        {
            String Fullname = "";
            int nNameCount = randomizer.Next() % 3;
            nNameCount++;
            while (nNameCount>0)
            {
                if (Fullname.Length == 0)
                    Fullname = GenerateName();
                else
                    Fullname += " " + GenerateName();
                nNameCount--;
            }
            return Fullname;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext();

            for (int i = 0; i < 300000;i++ )
            {
                int personid = randomizer.Next() % 100;
                Person p = db.Persons.FirstOrDefault(_p=> _p.ssn == personid.ToString());
                if (p == null)
                {
                    p = new Person();
                    p.name = GenerateFullname();
                    p.ssn = personid.ToString();
                    p.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    db.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(p);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                    Adresse a = new Adresse();
                    a.person_id = p.id;
                    a.Gate = GenerateFullname();
                    a.Poststed = GenerateName();
                    a.By = GenerateName();
                    db.Adresses.InsertOnSubmit(a);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                    int jj = randomizer.Next() % 10 + 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < jj; j++)
                    {
                        Item item = new Item();
                        item.ItemNumber = randomizer.Next().ToString();
                        item.PersonID = p.id;
                        db.Items.InsertOnSubmit(item);
                        db.SubmitChanges();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    int jj = randomizer.Next() % 10 + 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < jj; j++)
                    {
                        int number = randomizer.Next();
                        Item item = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(_i => _i.ItemNumber == number.ToString());
                        if (item == null)
                        {
                            item = new Item();
                            item.ItemNumber = number.ToString();
                            item.PersonID = p.id;
                            db.Items.InsertOnSubmit(item);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            item.ItemNumber = randomizer.Next().ToString();
                        }
                        db.SubmitChanges();
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\r" + i + "   ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How much is it slowing down by?  Do you have any printouts of execution times to give us an idea of the scale here?

Comment: Have you tried profiling the app with ANTS Profiler or something similar to see were the issue might be?

Comment: @Servy: We did some data transfers on one app (with false customer data etc) just to do a sampling and in the beginning the app churned up about 6000 customers and maybe 3-8 items pr customer (randomly) pr minute, but after 5 minutes we were down to 1500 customers a minute, and 10 minutes after that we were in about 150 customers pr minute.

Comment: Xaisoft: Prbably not enough, but done that just a bit and the things taking the longest time is the Linq2Sql-part.

Maybe one should go with precompiled queries, but that appears to be something for a different app as we're gonna do it 'the old way' using SqlCommands etc.

Still i would LOVE to find out what's wrong :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to fix the problem. Some of the data was already "preloaded" (lazy loading?), and this wasn't disabled. Thus if you want control over what LINQ should do, and NOT do "behind the scenes", you should disable this feature.

```
DatabaseContext.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Rookie mistake, sad to say :-|

Answer (score 2):

You are using a single data-context. A data-context includes:

- an identity manager
- a change tracker

That means the more objects you touch, the fatter it gets. And the fatter it gets, the more work it has to do each time. And the slower it gets.

Don't keep a data-context longer than you need; a unit of work, for example, should be a firmly small and discreet unit.

**THEN START AFRESH**

Since L2S implements `IDisposable`, you should also ensure you dispose each data-context you use.

Comment: Yeah, in this case I use a single datacontext, and so I did in the beginning of the company app. But after reading up a bit on things I found out that you shouldn't use a data context for longer than necessary, and so I changed it to just create a datacontext whenever it was needed.

I.E:

     bool AddNewItemToPerson(Item item, Person person)
     {
        using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
     {
      // verify person exists or add it
     // verify club membership or add it
     // verify existing item or add it
       db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a similar behavior on an app I am working on. In my case I the cause is very large memory consumption by the SQL server.

If you are running in a similar setup (1 machine with client, SQL server, visual studio), take a look at the memory usage on your computer (process explorer, add the virtual size column and sort by it). if you are seeing a correlation between the slowdown and the virtual size --> treat your computer to some more RAM, or clean up unnecessary processes.

BTW - if the answer about data context is relevant to your case then fix that issue first.

Comment: The app connects to a database in the company app, and memory is not a problem I think. Another co-worker suggested we might try to just do "dbContext.SubmitChanges()" extremly seldom as that might slow things down, but we've come so far that we've kinda abandoned Linq2Sql on this app and going with pure Sqlcommands. That's a sin as Linq2Sql is very easy to write code with.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some major improvements when calling Linq2SQl functions that only return 1 or a few items using pre-compiled LINQ statements.

For more information please check out this post http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/unexpected-benefits-of-precompilation-of-linq/

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that too, but since I'm using linq quite a bit there'll be a lot of precompiled and I hoped that there'd be another way and an obvious coding error by me. Of course it's hard to say what's wrong since ppl don't have the code.

Comment: Yeah I would say always precompile linq statements that return a single object or a small list of objects. I've seen HUGE performance increases by doing this however the code is super UGLY for the precompiled statements, that's my only complaint with them.